# How to fix : cannot bind 'tcp:5037': Address already in use ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon?

Tags: command-line, android

I want to push a file to an sdcard and emulator and refresh each emulator again.

This is my code

```
echo "=======PUSH photos AND REFRESH EACH EMULATOR========"
echo "${EMULATORS[0]}"
echo "${EMULATORS[1]}"
echo "${EMULATORS[2]}"
adb kill-server
sleep 30
adb start-server
sleep 30
echo "Trying to push to device ${EMULATORS[index]}"

adb -s ${EMULATORS[index]} push -p ~/dev/test_ttrumpet_portals/rspec_automation/link_android_appium_tests/spec/photo /mnt/sdcard/Pictures
sleep 50

echo "================REFRESH EMULATORS===================="

for index in "${!EMULATORS[@]}" #start all emulators
do
    echo "Trying to refresh ${EMULATORS[index]}"
    adb -s ${EMULATORS[index]} shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///sdcard
    sleep 30
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out which application or process is listening on the port by using the following commands:

```
udo netstat -peant | grep ":5037"
```

OR

```
lsof -i :80
```

Get the process id of the process listening to that port and kill it using:

```
sudo kill -9 <process id>
```

Comment: 1. Thank you. I have multiple emulators on, how can I use this for them?

Comment: @SibabalweMvelo use the code in your emulator for loop

Comment: Every time I kill-server, it starts itself on same port, and the error persists. Emulator never starts. I checked using sudo lsof -i <port>, there is a new pid for adb each time you kill server. Starting server is useless because it is already up, and command fails.